# Code-behind stopped sending requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a page which requests information from several apis, some of them with javascript and some of them from code-behind (c#). As of today, my VS 2010 asp.net development server has stopped sending out any code-behind requests. The js requests work as expected. It's not a code thing, and I copied my project folder to a different computer and it worked fine there.

I was playing around with the hosts file yesterday, so I figured thats where the problem is, but i restored the hosts file back to the default xp settings, and that didn't help.

I also tried repairing my VS installation, to no avail.

Any ideas? I'm almost tearing my hair out!

Thanks in advance!

SOLVED:

Holy #$%^$%^&

It's a miracle I figured out what the problem was...I'm located in Israel, where we just switched to daylight savings time yesterday. This morning I changed the time on my pc. Our request oauth includes a timestamp, which the receiving end somehow didn't accept because of what looked to it like the wrong time. I set the clock on my pc back an hour, and now it's working......

Comment: Modified original title since there is no such term like "Visual Studio code behind"

Comment: use Fiddler2 to monitoring your request. Maybe there is a proxy or a firewall blocking yours messages.

Comment: 2GDev, thanks I had forgotten about Fiddler2. First it showed me a 502, but after clearing my browser cache it's showing me 401, which I understand to be an authorization issue. Which doesn't make sense because, as mentioned before, the same code is working from another pc on the same network/IP...

Comment: @Phil: Have you checked to make sure that the necessary ports are open and configured correctly?

Comment: @James, do you mean as regards my firewall? I disabled the whole thing and it still didn't work.

Comment: If it works on another computer but not on yours, that would suggest that the problem is specific to your machine.

Comment: @ James, I agree. The question is: what is the problem!

Comment: Instead of editing your question you should post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy #$%^$%^&

It's a miracle I figured out what the problem was...I'm located in Israel, where we just switched to daylight savings time yesterday. This morning I changed the time on my pc. Our request oauth includes a timestamp, which the receiving end somehow didn't accept because of the